# Configurable ruby logger setup: Logger.new().level = variable

Tags: ruby, constants, logging

I want to change the logging level of an application (ruby).

```
require 'logger'

config = { :level => 'Logger::WARN' }

log = Logger.new STDOUT
log.level = Kernel.const_get config[:level]
```

Well, the irb wasn't happy with that and threw "NameError: wrong constant name Logger::WARN" in my face.  Ugh!  I was insulted.

I could do this in a case/when to solve this, or do log.level = 1, but there must be a more elegant way!

Does anyone have any ideas?

-daniel

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why don't you just use the literal constant in your `config` hash?

```
config = { :level => Logger::WARN }
```

Then you don't have to fool around with `const_get` or anything like that; you can simply do `log.level = config[:level]`.

If it *absolutely must* be a string, you can drop the namespace prefix and call `const_get` on the `Logger` module:

```
irb(main):012:0> Logger.const_get 'WARN'
=> 2
```

If it *really really* has to be the qualified string, you might try using [this blog's `qualified_const_get` method](http://redcorundum.blogspot.com/2006/05/kernelqualifiedconstget.html) (which is not a built-in!).

Comment: The constant cannot be stored in the config, because the config is loaded from a yaml file, but Logger.const_get 'WARN' works great for me!